# What does "X have subsequently recovered, and so might Y" mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence, phrase-usage

I have question about bold, italicize sentence below.

Many fairly common amphibian species declared all but extinct after severe declines in the 1950s and 1960s have subsequently recovered, **and so might the apparently declining populations that have generated the current appearance of an amphibian crisis.**

My teacher told me 
so might works following example.
example to show how 'so might' works. "So might" means something like 'might do the same thing.'

My grandfather gave me a book for my birthday, and so might my grandmother. 
My grandfather gave me a book for my birthday, and my grandmother might do the same thing / might give me a book [for my birthday].
​
However,
and the apparently declining populations that have generated the current appearance of amphibian crisis might have subsequently recovered. 
does not make sense...

Is there any one who can help me understood this?

Comment: You haven't quite understood the example about the books, the tenses are different in the two parts of the sentence. Your grandfather has already given you his book but you have not yet had one from your grandmother, although you might get one from her in the future. If you apply the change of tense to the amphibian populations I think you will find that it makes sense. The second part of the sentence about the amphibians means "...the populations which seem to have declined ... might recover in the future in the same manner as the populations which declined in the 1950s and 1960s

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence is: ... and **so might** the apparently declining populations  ...  -- this suggests that the recovery might happen in future

Your translation is: ... *amphibian crisis* **might have** subsequently recovered ... -- which suggest that it has already recovered

I think the correct translation would maintain the tense.

So it should be: ... the *apparently declining populations* **might** subsequently recover ... -- this also suggests that the recovery might happen in future

So the meaning would be, that the amphibian population decreasing (the population in future will be less that the population now) which gives the appearance of a crisis.
But it might recover (the population in future might not decrease), and the situation might cease to appear as a crisis.

Answer (score 0):

Might is similar to "may" in the sense of possibility. Might is somewhat less possible than may. So to say something "might" happen means that there is a possibility that it will happen. Those amphibians have a chance at a comeback.

Might: "Less probability or possibility that may. M-W